# strip_tags not working properly

Tags: php, smarty

I am using this in my tpl file , like

```
{strip_tags({$obj->getfunc()})}
```

and it gives mes error like `syntax error: unrecognized tag:`

is anything wrong with the syntax ??

full error message

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Smarty error: [in file.tpl line 7]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: strip_tags({$obj->getfunc()
```

Comment: can you show us what `$obj->getfunc()` is?

Comment: Post exactly the error you receive. Is this a Smarty system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
strip_tags({$obj->getfunc()})
```

The problem here is the `{}` curly braces. I don't know why you thought you needed these, but they're not required.

[edit]

I see you've edited the question/comments to note that you're using Smarty. Now the curly braces make sense.

I guess you started off with just `{$obj->getfunc()}`, and decided to do `strip_tags()` on it to prevent hacks.

The `{}` braces are part of Smarty, so you should only use them this way for the entire block of code. So you need them outside of the `strip_tags() function, and not inside, on the method call as you had it previously.

So instead of this `strip_tags({$obj->getfunc()})`, you should have something like this:

```
{strip_tags($obj->getfunc())}
```

Hope that helps.

[edit 2]

Okay, I'm a PHP dev, not a smarty dev. The code above is valid PHP (not counting the `{}` braces). But maybe smarty doesn't like that.

I googled and found this page on the Smarty website: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tags.tpl

That page gives some specific Smarty syntax for strip_tags, so based on that, it looks like you code should look like this:

```
{$obj->getfunc()|strip_tags}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd run this function not at presentation level but at business logic level.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{` from JavaScript code in your template with `{literal}` and `}` with `{/literal}`